# Change contrast in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a pure Numpy function to change the contrast of an RGB image (that is represented as a Numpy uint8 array), however, the function I wrote doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Here is an example image:

[image]

And here is a function that uses PIL and works fine:

```
def change_contrast(img, factor):
    def contrast(pixel):
        return 128 + factor * (pixel - 128)
    return img.point(contrast)

from PIL import Image

img = Image.fromarray(img.astype(np.uint8))
img1 = change_contrast(img, factor=2.0)
```

Output:

[image]

Now here is a pure Numpy function, which, in my opinion, does the exact same thing as the other function above, but it doesn't work at all:

```
def change_contrast2(img, factor):
    return 128 + factor * (img - 128)

img1 = change_contrast2(img, factor=2.0)
```

where `img` is a Numpy array. The output is this:

[image]

I don't understand what's going on and would be happy about any hints!

Comment: I suspect the numpy array has an unsigned dtype causing wraparound on underflow. Could you please post the output of `img.dtype`? - Sorry, just saw it's indeed `uint8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is underflow of unsigned integers:

```
>>> a = np.array((64, 128, 192), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> a
array([ 64, 128, 192], dtype=uint8)
>>> a-128
array([192,   0,  64], dtype=uint8) # note the "wrong" value at pos 0
```

One way of avoiding this is coercion or type promotion:

```
factor = float(factor)
np.clip(128 + factor * img - factor * 128, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

As factor is a float the dtype of the product `factor * img` is promoted to float. As floats can handle negative numbers this eliminates the underflow.

To be able to convert back to `uint8` we clip to the range that can be expressed by this type.

Comment: apparently I can't correct a spelling mistake so I will leave it in your capable hands .... .astype .... currently, astpye

Comment: Thanks a lot! Weirdly, converting back to `uint8` after the contrast change seems to be just as important as the other things. The image looks terrible if I leave the array dtype as float. I don't understand why, but it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, create your numpy array with type int32 and do the contrast operation. Then before plotting the image use the following function to convert it to uint8. As Paul mentioned in the comments, the problem is that numpy is wrapping around with over/underflows.

```
def as_uint8(img) :
    latch = np.zeros_like(img)
    latch[:] = 255
    zeros = np.zeros_like(img)

    d = np.maximum(zeros, img)
    d = np.minimum(latch, d)

    return np.asarray(d, dtype='uint8')
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Converting the dtype back to uint8 after the contrast change seems to be crucial. I don't understand why, but thanks a lot!